# Unable to use pybind11 headers

Tags: c++, path, header-files, pybind11

I just want to be able to compile a C++ program with the following line

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

I have tried to set the path with cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-march=native -O3 -I /usr/include/python3.9/ -I /home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include/")
```

Did not work. Direct path to file in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS leads to file not found.

I tried to add the header path to the bashrc:

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include
```

```
$ pybind11/pybind11.h
bash: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
```

If I path to:

`$HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11`

```
$ pybind11.h
bash: pybind11.h: command not found...
```

None of that makes the header visible!

This stuff always works when I try to import headers in C++.

The file

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h
```

is definitely on the system.
I can do this just fine:

```
#include </home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure out how to use the installed pybind11[global], so I just created a git repo for my project and added pybind11 as a submodule.

Then in my cmake I added `add_subdirectory(extern/pybind11)` as requested by the docs. I think this builds the source in the directory.

Then I had to use `target_include_directories(sps INTERFACE extern/pybind11/include)` so that the sources in target sps could use the headers.